# Why does not "link:.." work for library examples?

Tags: react-native

For my company I am developing a react-native library. I am trying to bundle an example application with the library.

If I create an application and but the library in a subfolder I can use "react-native-my-library": "link:modules/react-native-my-library" in my examples package.json.

But If I put the example as a subfolder of the library I can no longer use link.

I can use "file:..", but that copies everything into node_modules instead. Using "file:..", running `yarn` and then changing it back to "link:.." and running `yarn` also works!

I have generated new libraries using `npx create...` which do provide a working example app folder inside the library **but** for some reason (probably because of this bug) they use a lot of compiler/babel/config magic to get that working.

- vscode is happy and finds the library without issues
- `yarn tsc` is happy and finds the library without issues
- `yarn ts-node` is happy and finds the library without issues
  But the command that xcode runs is not happy!

`/opt/homebrew/bin/node node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev true --reset-cache --bundle-output ...`

```
  node_modules
  ../node_modules
  3 |
  4 | import DeviceList from './components/DeviceList';
> 5 | import {Reader} from 'react-native-my-library';
```

```
⋊> ls -l node_modules/react-native-my-library
node_modules/react-native-my-library@ -> ../..
```

If this is the intended behaviour could someone please point me to the why and what the correct solution is? Thank you.